# What happened to microsoft.bcl.simd?

Tags: c#, vector, sse, simd

I distinctly remember the announcements of the SSE-enhanced vectors for C#, and I know we did some tests with them only a short while ago. Now, it seems they vanished from the internet. The NuGet packages from 2014 still exist, but are delisted:

> The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.

Some older news articles that references them are still available, but nothing new.

Was this project officially discontinued or was it merged into something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are a part of the .NET 4.6 inside the [`System.Numerics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.numerics(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.

From [*Numerics in the .NET Framework - SIMD-enabled vector types*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/numerics#simd-enabled-types) (emphasis mine):

> The SimD-enabled vector types are implemented in IL, which allows them to be used on non-SimD-enabled hardware and JIT compilers. **To take advantage of SIMD instructions, your 64-bit apps must be compiled by the new 64-bit JIT Compiler for managed code, which is included with the .NET Framework 4.6**; it adds SIMD support when targeting x64 processors.
>
> SIMD can also be downloaded as a NuGet package. The NuGET package also includes a generic Vector structure that allows you to create a vector of any primitive numeric type. (The primitive numeric types include all numeric types in the System namespace except for Decimal.) In addition, the Vector structure provides a library of convenience methods that you can call when working with vectors.